# Recursively search in files for a range of Unicode characters

Tags: file, search

How can recursively search in files for a range of Unicode characters? In my particular problem I need to find all files with at least 1 cyrillic character inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recursively log all files with non-Unicode characters I used:

`brew install pcregrep`

`pcregrep --color='auto' -nr "[\x80-\xFF]" . >> output.txt`